# Spatie laravel view model multiple view models for home page

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using [spatie laravel view models](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-view-models) and trying to send multiple model objects to view the blade template.

```
    $viewModel1 = new ViewModel1(
        $array1,
        $array2,
    );

    $viewModel2 = new ViewModel2(
        $array1,
        $array2,
    );

    return view('home', $viewModel1); // It's working fine.
```

I'm reusing the multiple view model in different controllers.

Trying to send multiple objects as following:

```
    return view('home', $viewModel1, $viewModel2); // not working
```

Also, tried after merging and etc. But still not working. Any way to fix this.

Comment: did you try: `return view('home', compact('viewModel1', 'viewModel2');` ?

Comment: also try ```return view('home')->with("viewModel1",$viewModel1)->with("viewModel2",$viewModel2);```